# How to print div with containing data using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to print particular div of a webpage and that div containing some string. for example: in textbox containing name of the person.

Now when I print page at that time in print preview it's showing textbox only without any string(data).

```js
function showPopup(divName) {
  var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
  var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
  newWin.document.open();
  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
  newWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function() {
    newWin.close();
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="service-job-form" name="service-job-form">
    <div id="printableArea">
      <label for="CustomerId" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5 input-group">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="CustomerName" name="CustomerName" required data-provide="typeahead" class="typeahead search-query form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Customer Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print" id="bodyWrapper" onclick="showPopup('printableArea');" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're code throws an error. It might be fixing that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help:

```js
function showPopup() {
  var name = $('#CustomerName').val();
  var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
  newWin.document.open();
  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + name + '</body></html>');
  newWin.document.close();
  setTimeout(function() {
    newWin.close();
  }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from an input field the use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`. So your code would read:

```
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.value + '</body></html>');
```